# What's the most practical approach to handling null inequality?

Tags: teradata

I don't understand Teradata's implementation for null inequality comparisons.  You can run this SQL right in SQLA:

```
select 
    null x, current_date y,
    case
        when 
            not 
            --ZEROIFNULL(x) = ZEROIFNULL(y)
            ((x is null and y is null) or x = y)
        then 1 
        else 0 
    end z
```

You will notice that `z` returns 0, but I feel that it should return 1.  Here's my reasoning:

`x is null and y is null`  This should return false since only `x` is null.

`x = y`  This should return false since both are not equal.

However, when I put `not` in front of the entire expression, it returns false.  When you say `not false`, you should get true.  The only solution I can think of is to use `ZEROIFNULL` or one of Teradata's other null-related functions, but that seems more like a hack to get null inequality to work.

How can I get null inequality to work the way it seems like it should?

**Update:**  Thanks for your answer, dnoeth.  Nulls are tricky, and your explanation of `unknown` lead me to [this very informative Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29).

Now that I understand better, here's my fully modified SQL.  What I am trying to do is determine whether or not to move a record to an audit table.  I only want to audit a record if 1) its `AuditOverride` flag = 1 OR at least one of the fields has changed.  Throwing an `unknown` into a condition that contains multiple expressions will result in the entire expression returning `unknown`.  Because putting `not` in front of `unknown` also results in `unknown`, I use a `case` statement to convert that to 0 (like `zeroifnull`).

dnoeth, if you see a better way to handle inequality comparisons such as this, I am all for hearing your ideas.

```
select 
    1 Table1Field1, 1 Table1Field2,
    1 Table2Field1, 1 Table2Field2,
    0 AuditOverride,
    case 
        when 
            AuditOverride = 1 or
            case
                when 
                    (
                        (Table1Field1 is null and Table1Field2 is null) or 
                        Table1Field1 = Table1Field2
                    ) and
                    (
                        (Table2Field1 is null and Table2Field2 is null) or 
                        Table2Field1 = Table2Field2
                    ) and
                    1=1
                then 0 --no differences in values; do not audit
                else 1 --at least 1 change has occurred; move to audit table
            end = 1
        then 1
        else 0 
    end MoveToAuditTable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not only a Teradata related question, this is three-way logic every RDBMS should return the same :-)

Based on SQL's Three-Valued Logic and De Morgan's law:

**not (A or B)** is the same as **(not A) AND (not B)**.

Any comparison with NULL returns UNKNOWN which is not the same as FALSE, NOT UNKNOWN results in UNKNOWN again.

So your condition is **NOT FALSE AND NOT UNKNOWN** = **TRUE AND UNKNOWN** = **UNKNOWN**

You must change it to:

```
select 
    null x, current_date y,
    case
        when 
            ((x is null and y is null) or x = y)
        then 0
        else 1 
    end z
```

Comment: This really helped my understanding of pesky nulls.  I also tried this in Oracle and you are correct that it behaves the same way.  However, Oracle and Teradata don't always treat nulls the same.  If you run `select 'a' || null || 'z' from dual` in Oracle, you get `az`.  However, if you run `select 'a' || null || 'z'` in Teradata, you get `null`.

Comment: This is a known "feature" in Oracle, there's no difference between an empty string '' and a NULL. In your case Oracle treats it like a '', but there's no consistent rule, e.g. in REPLACE it's '' while in TRANSLATE it's NULL :-)